# Uneven figure border on the saved figure with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have plot with code like below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [1000,2000,500,8000,3000]
y1 = [1050,3000,2000,4000,6000]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(linewidth=2, edgecolor="black",facecolor="orange")

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.bar(x, y)
ax2.plot(x, y1, 'o-', color="red" )

ax1.set_xlabel('X data')
ax1.set_ylabel('Counts', color='g')
ax2.set_ylabel('Detection Rates', color='b')
plt.savefig(r"C:\Users\moys\Desktop\qqq.jpg")
plt.show()
```

It is displaying correctly. However the save `.jpg` fine seems to have thick borders on left & top when compared to right & bottom. Below is the save pic.

In another script the border is not visible at all (even when the line width is 10). How do I fix this & get the same line width border on all sides?

[image]

**Update**

With `bbox_inches='tight'` added to `plt.savefig(r"./data/qqq.jpg", bbox_inches='tight')` the saved file is like below.

The border on the right is completely gone & the top is also thinner now.

[image]

Comment: If you add the following parameters when saving, the gaps will be the same. `plt.savefig(r"./data/qqq.jpg", bbox_inches='tight')`

Comment: It does seem to make things worse. Please see the **update** in the question.

Comment: Also, there is a function to add gaps so you can find the best fit. Units are in inches. `plt.savefig(r"./data/qqq.jpg", bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches=0.2)`